# New to Bootstrap - I have a goofy grid puzzle to solve

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning Bootstrap and have a puzzle for you... I am trying to create a grid layout that changes order in the following pattern.  I'm having trouble with pushing and pulling the classes in the proper way.  I'd include my code but I'm afraid it's so far from the solution that you'd probably laugh.  Here's what i'm going for:

```
    In Medium/Large Desktop:       Small:          X-small:
    [A      ]                      [A   ]          [A]
    [B      ]                      [B   ]          [1]
    [C      ]                      [1][2]          [B]
    [1][2][3]                      [C   ]          [2]
    [D      ]                      [D   ]          [C]
    [E      ]                      [3][4]          [3]
    [F      ]                      [E   ]          [D]
    [4][5][6]                      [F   ]          [4]
                                   [5][6]          [E]
                                                   [5] 
                                                   [F]
                                                   [6]
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bootstrap (AFAIK) can't change source order....only flexbox can do that.

Comment: @Paulie_D It can, use the push/pull classes

Comment: Is it possible to push or pull the divs into this layout?

Comment: Probably, though it's fairly complex. Perhaps you could start us off with the xs version?

Comment: What's the HTML structure?

Comment: OK...I though it could push/pull left/right...not up / down but it'll be good to learn something new. :)

Comment: @Paulie_D is correct, I don't think it's possible to do this with Bootstrap out of the box. Push and Pull are used to change the horizontal order, not vertical.

Comment: Hmm.  If this isn't possible with bootstrap is it possible with any other grid systems?  Flexbox?

Comment: Flexbox is newer css. See caniuse.com. The best way to do this is to use server side detection and server up html based on the device. https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Even with push and pull you can't "skip" other divs. So this is the best I can do:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">B</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">C</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">3</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">4</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">D</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">E</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">F</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">5</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">6</div>
```

Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/rema/pen/bpkKJ)